# MS Purview Oracle scan: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: azure, azure-purview

I'm trying to use MS Purview to scan an Oracle source (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0) with a self-hosted Integration Runtime (Windows 2022, IR version 5.17.8186.1).

---

Testing the connection from the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime is successful:

[image]

---

However, testing the connection from the Governance Portal fails with **java.lang.IllegalStateException**

[image]

---

This is the Integration Runtime error log during this event:

> TestConnection failed, error message: 'Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.ConnectorPluginException,Message=Connector Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.GenericMitiConnectors,StackTrace=   at Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.GenericMitiConnectors.GenericMitiConnection.TestConnection()
> at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.InteractiveTaskFactoryV2.ConnectorTestConnection(ConnectionSetting connectionSetting, TestConnectionV2Response response)
> at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.InteractiveTaskFactoryV2.TestConnection(TestConnectionV2Request request, TestConnectionV2Response response, CancellationToken token)
> at Microsoft.DataTransfer.TransferTask.InteractiveTask`2.Execute(),''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.ConnectorPluginException,Message=Connector Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.GenericMitiConnectors,StackTrace=   at Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.GenericMitiConnectors.MitiLogger.throwError()
> at Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.GenericMitiConnectors.GenericMitiConnection.TestConnection(),''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.ConnectorPluginException,Message=Connector Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.ConnectorPluginException,Message=Connector Exception: The Java process did not complete successfully,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.ConnectorPluginException,Message=Connector Exception: The tool failed with error code ERROR_TEST,Source=,'.
> Log ID: Error

---

**Any idea how to get this scan to succeed?**

Comment: [Troubleshoot your connections in Microsoft Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/troubleshoot-connections) and [IllegalStateException --> What are the reasons that can cause this](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4327072/illegalstateexception-what-are-the-reasons-that-can-cause-this)

Comment: Thanks @DeepDave-MT.  I've gone through the Purview troubleshooting link and still the issue persists.  The illegalStateException link you provided does not apply since this is MS code I don't control.